# Hard time getting input from scanner

Tags: java

My scanner doesn't seem to stop, all I'm trying to do is get input from the user and then stop when someone types done. I'm adding a space into my array list because my information in my array list is saved with an additional space, so I'm just adding a space to my text coming in. Any help? What I have so far doesn't stop.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scan.hasNextLine()){

    String line = scan.toString();
    InPlayerNames.add(line+" ");

    if (line.toString().equals("done")) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: line should not be scan.toString(); It should read scan.nextLine() (next input from System.in)

Comment: There's no need to use `line.toString()`; just `line` is sufficient.

Comment: There are many tutorials out there that perfectly explain how to use the scanner class. Read them, or at least the javadoc for the classes you intend to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scan.toString() is returning textual representation of scan i.e. returning location in memory because toString() method is used to return textual representation of object it is called on.

Use scan.nextLine() everywhere in place of scan.toString() and it’ll stop on getting “done”.

Answer (score 4):

Use `scan.nextLine()` and not `scan.toString()`.

The scanner, as it is, is stuck in the while loop; calling `toString()` on `scan` simply gives a text representation of the `scan` object.

Answer (score 0):

You're while loop is checking that your scanner HAS a next line (good), but when you are not ACTAULLY setting line to that next line. You should say 
    String line = scan.nextLine instead. You are currently only setting line to scan's LOCATION in memory. Therefore, in your if statement, line never equals "done".

Answer (score 0):

This code perfectly works fine for me.

```
package TestPrograms;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the names:");
        ArrayList<String> playernames = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (scan.hasNextLine()){

            String line = scan.nextLine();

            playernames.add(line+" ");

            if (line.equals("done")||(line.equals("Done"))) {
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Entered names are : ");
        for(String name:playernames) {
            System.out.println(name);

        }


    }

}
```

You should use scan.nextLine() to get the input, not scan.toString().